# how to get geojson of mainly cities of all of country of the world

Tags: highcharts, geojson, echarts

I'm making a map use echarts with geojson mapdata,but i need a geojson resource that contain main cities of all of country of the world,i had looked for everywhere on website ,but the mostly resource is just have border of country not has cities border data. and i also checked the highcharts mapdata resource but the crs option is ESPG type .i need the  Longitude latitude coordinates

Comment: Show the code you have written so far, so we can help you out.

Comment: `{
  "type":"Feature",
  "properties":{"name":"Macquarie Island"},
  "geometry":{
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
       [
        [158.8657332690001,-54.749932549999876],
        [158.83822675900007,-54.75042083099995],
        [158.8320418630001,-54.73805103999992],
        [158.832367384,-54.73365650799993]`

Answer (score 7):

depends on how many city do you want?

If you want 36430 city with only city name, go here

https://github.com/drei01/geojson-world-cities

If you want 1240 city with lots of details info go here: (choose populated-place)

http://geojson.xyz

if you only need major 120 city with only city name go here: (choose world city)
https://github.com/mapbox/mapping

Answer (score 4):

Go to http://geojson.xyz and look for "populated places" and "populated places simple"

You can also take GeoJSON from website NaturalEarhData.com available at Github e.g  [ne_10m_populated_places.geojson](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_10m_populated_places.geojson) and [ne_10m_populated_places_simple.geojson](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_10m_populated_places_simple.geojson)
In fact, GeoJSON.xyz takes the data from NaturalEarthData.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have geojson of continents, countries, country groupings, regions and states of all the world:

https://github.com/rapomon/geojson-places